# Traefik persistent volumes with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I want to setup a docker compose environment running a backend, frontend, and a Traefik image. The Traefik environment should use a persistent volume to store the certificates. Otherwise, Traefik will request a new certificate during each start and exceed the Let's Encrypt rate limits.

I expected a single docker volume to be created, but I see 5 volumes and it's unclear why and I don't know if the persistent storage is used.

In my application's folder `myproject`, I have a docker compose configuration file `compose.yaml`:

```yaml
# compose.yaml
services:
  # frontend & backend services removed
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.10"
    container_name: "traefik"
    restart: always
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=false"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      # Configure letsencrypt
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=<my email address>"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/certificates/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - traefik_webgateway
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "traefik-public-certificates-volume:/certificates" # using volume for persistent storage

# Explicitly define the network
networks:
  traefik_webgateway:
    external: true

# Explicitly define docker volume which stores certificates
volumes:
  traefik-public-certificates-volume:  # using volume for persistent storage
```

When starting with a fresh setup

```bash
docker system prune
docker network create traefik_webgateway
docker compose up
```

and then listing all volumes using `docker volume ls`, I somehow have 5 volumes:

```bash
user@ubuntu:~/myproject# docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     XXXXXXXXXXf5842b884e84fc165d275ca139f3a296331d154c1cffec2a753acd
local     myproject_traefik-public-certificates
local     myproject_traefik_traefik-public-certificates-volume
local     traefik-public-certificates
local     traefik-public-certificates-volume
```

Why do I have 5 docker images? And how do I ensure that Traefik is using a persistent volume?

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on my setup. After running the **docker-compose.yaml**, it only created 1 volume (**test-traefik_traefik-public-certificates-volume**) (Others were created before, please have a look below printscreen).

To understand and a fresh start, delete all volumes before running file:

```
docker volume rm [volumeName]
```

Network Creation:

[image]

To see/view the content of the volume for the confirmation. You can create another container (e.g. ubuntu:20.04) that connects to the existing volume, then enter the container to see the volume content.

```
docker run -it --rm -v test-traefik_traefik-public-certificates-volume:/traefik-cert ubuntu:20.04 /bin/bash
```

After running docker-compose.yaml:

[image]

Or, another way is the binding mount (on the host machine) directly without using volume.

docker-compose.yaml, create file path on the host and connect it:

```
volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./<filepathOnHost>/certificates:/certificates" # using a bind mount for persistent storage
```